# How to ask the user for a specific path to be used with open()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I'm trying to build a file transfer system with python3 sockets. I have the connection and sending down but my issue right now is that the file being sent has to be in the same directory as the program, and when you receive the file, it just puts the file into the same directory as the program.

How can I get a user to input the location of the file to be sent and select the location of the file to be sent to?

Comment: Do you have some sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're opening files with:

```
open("filename","r")
```

If you do not provide an absolute path, the open function will always default to a relative path. So, if I wanted to open a file such as /mnt/storage/dnd/5th_edition.txt, I would *have* to use:

```
open("/mnt/storage/dnd/4p5_edition","r")
```

And if I wanted to copy this file to /mnt/storage/trash/ I would *have* to use the absolute path as well:

```
open("/mnt/storage/trash/4p5_edition","w")
```

If instead, I decided to use this:

```
open("mnt/storage/trash/4p5_edition","w")
```

Then I would get an IOError if there wasn't a directory named mnt with the directories storage/trash in my present folder. If those folders *did* exist in my present folder, then it would end up in /whatever/the/path/is/to/my/current/directory/mnt/storage/trash/4p5_edition, rather than /mnt/storage/trash/4p5_edition.

Answer (score 0):

since you said that the file will be placed in the same path where the program is, the following code might work

```
import os
filename = "name.txt"
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

like you say, the file should be in the same folder of the project so you have to replace it, or to define a function that return the right file path into your `open()` function, It's a way that you can use to reduce the time of searching a solution to your problem brother.

It should be something like :

```
import os

filename = "the_full_path_of_the_fil/name.txt"
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),filename))
```

then you can use the value of the `f` variable as a path to the directory of where the file is in.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple, just get the path from user:

```
subpath = raw_input("File path =  ")
print subpath
file = open(subpath + str(file_name), 'w+')
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

I think that's all you need.

Comment: The question asks about Python 3, but `raw_input` is Python 2 only.